# Triangles Drawn in XNA

Tags: c#, xna

I am looking for a way to get the amount of triangles drawn per frame in XNA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://forums.xna.com/forums/p/25179/139375.aspx

```
foreach (ModelMesh mesh in Model.Meshes)
{
   foreach (ModelMeshPart part in mesh.MeshParts)
   {
       polyCount += part.PrimitiveCount;
   }
}
```

You can also use something like PIX and [PerfHUD](http://developer.nvidia.com/object/nvperfhud_home.html)